# How to insert only one column data into a table from another table in SQL

Tags: mysql

I've two table `languages` and `category`.

```
  Languages                Category
+-----------+           +---------+------+
|  Language |           |   Name  | Year |
+-----------+           +---------+------+
|  English  |           | English | 2018 |
|  German   |           | German  | 2018 |
|  French   |           | French  | 2018 |
+-----------+           +---------+------+
```

Now, Problem is i've query like

> INSERT INTO categories (`name`)  select language from languages ;

But, i want to add those years(always same year) too at the same time of Language insertion into `category` table which is `table 2`.

Comment: What does your expected output table look like?

Comment: You might want to consider to normalize better. The same data across multiple tables are prime candidates voor normalization.. Table  `Languages` should have the columns `id` and `language` and the table `Category` should have the columns `language_id` and `year`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may just insert a literal value for the year:

```
INSERT INTO categories (name, year)
SELECT language, 2018    -- or maybe use YEAR(NOW()) in place of 2018
FROM languages;
```

Literals can be specified in a select clause just as any column name may be specified.

Comment: Is it necessary to have same column names in two tables?

Comment: No, it's not, provided that you specify which columns you want to target for the insert.  That is to say, you can select any columns you want, and the names don't have anything to do with the target column names.

Comment: i used this query **INSERT INTO `citimela_db`.`tbl_categories` (`name`, `tbl_user_userid`,  `created_time`,`tbl_catalog_catalogid`)  select language, now(),4  from languages**

Comment: No...you are specifying 4 columns for insert, but selecting only 3 columns.  That won't work.

Comment: Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Answer (score 2):

seems you need year(curdate())

```
INSERT INTO categories (name, year) 
select language, year(curdate())
from languages ;
```

Comment: Better yet.  More flexible. +1